# Python-an integer is required

Tags: python

OK so this is my code, it's a base calculator that will convert base to base with no problem, but once the answer is over 9, I want the number to be represented as a letter, just like in base 16, 10 represent 'a', so I'm stuck on how can I do that just using Ascii tables. Right now the code is running well, if I type 1011,base2, I want to convert to base 16. So the output turns out to be 11, which is correct, but I want it to be 'b'

```
number = input("what's your number: ")
o_base = int(input("what is your oringal base: "))
base = int(input("what's the base you want to convert: "))
answer = ""
total = 0

for i, d in enumerate(reversed(number)):
    total = total + int(d) * o_base ** i

while (total != 0):
    answer  += str(total % base)
    total //= base

print (answer)
```

Comment: I bet there isn't a keyword argument called `answer` in int(). What are you trying to achieve doing that?

Comment: what are you trying to do? This is should give a SyntaxError the way it's written. I'm guessing you want answer = int(chr(i))

Comment: `i` in your case is actually a `str` type, therefore you are getting as you mentioned "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)". However, if `i` is an integer, it will raise a `TypeError` about `answer` being an invalid key argument for the `int` function..  So, what is it you are trying to do exactly. Please provide a better [MCVE].

Comment: @AbidHasan It will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: Just creating a string so every time I put the remaining number into "answer"

Comment: @JamesLiu What are you trying to accomplish with `int(answer = chr(i))`. What *exactly* is your intention with that line.

Comment: @idjaw just forget about that, I thought that would fix the problem by just putting a int infront of it

Comment: I strongly suggest you to specify what you really what to do, and also what you are expected.  To  be honest, there are some obvious problems in your code.

Comment: @JamesLiu Your question is pointing to an error message. That line is giving you that error message. I explained to you why you are getting that error message. That line can't just be ignored because that is your error. Provide a clearer [mcve] in order to actually understand what you are trying to do. We should not have to run your code and try to figure out what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, I hope this gives you guys a much better view

Comment: I think you should use a translation table.  Take a look at `str.translate()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can first convert your number into a Python integer using `int(number, base)`. Next all you need to do is convert it into you target base. This is often done using [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=divmod#divmod) which combines doing a division of two numbers and getting their remainder into one function.

To convert each digit into the correct number or letter, the easiest way is to create an string holding all of your required symbols in order, and then use an index into this to give you the one you need, e.g. `digits[0]` here will return `0`, and `digits[10]` would return `A`.

```
import string

number = input("What's your number: ")
o_base = int(input("What is your original base: "))
base = int(input("What is the base you want to convert to: "))

number = int(number, o_base)    
digits = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase  # 0 to 9 + A to Z
output = []

while number:
    number, remainder = divmod(number, base)
    output.insert(0, digits[remainder])

print(''.join(output))
```

This example works up to base 36 (i.e. 0 to 9 and A to Z). You could obviously extend `digits` to give you more symbols for higher bases.

Using a list to create the output avoids doing repetitive string concatenation which is not very efficient.